# Use jQuery element object as array key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use a jQuery element object as an array/object key?

Example:

```
var el = jQuery(this);
var test = {};
test[el] = "something strange";
```

Doing a:

```
jQuery.each(test, function(k,v){
    console.log(k);
});
```

just reports [object Object]

Is there a say that I could actually re-use the `k` as the original jQuery element object?

Comment: What are you ultimately hoping to accomplish? Since `el` is an object, if you want to associate `"something strange"` with that object, why not just add a property to the object?

Comment: @amnotiam This was an oversimplified example.  The actual usage would be that I needed an array of els, so it wouldn't work to add a property to it.

Comment: If you need an array of els isn't that just `var test = []; test.push(el); //etc`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

ECMAscript only allows for `strings` as key-values for objects.

---

What you could do instead, is to use the `id value` from a single node instead. So it might look like

```
var el = jQuery(this);
var test = {};
test[this.id] = "something strange";
```

That of course requires the node to have an id value.

Comment: Right, okay. Well, I guess I'll have to generate a generic ID for my purposes; simple enough.

Comment: The id is the attribute "id" on the element or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$.each([],function(i,v)){}` i is the index and v is the value.

Comment: The OP knows that. The question is why is the index reported as `"[object Object]"` (noting that in this case the "index" is a key or property name, given OP is working with a plain object not an array), and is it possible in JS to use an object as a property name.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the object converted to a string (`'[object Object]'`) as soon as you tried to assign it as an array key. For simple hashes, you could conceivably serialize them into a key:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar' },
    key = JSON.stringify(obj),
    obj2 = { key: 'something strange' };
```

Generally, though, you'll want to avoid this kind of thing. You might use parallel arrays containing the objects and messages, instead:

```
var keys = [ {foo: 'bar'}],
    values = [ 'something strange' ];
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to define an object and then push to array.

```
var obj = {};
obj[foo] = 'bar';
ary.push(obj);
```